# how to change a control's position in uwp?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a grid control, two rows and two columns.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="row1"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="column1"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Now I have another , by default it's position is in row1.
When the window width is larger than 1024, I want to set gridX's position to column1.

I just want to know the change position code, thanks.

Comment: 2 Things: 1.) what did you try so far? 2.) I am not quite sure, what you are trieing to achive. What do you add to your grid and what do you mean with gridX?

Comment: @Dai edited my question and delete <Grid x:Name="gridX"/>

Comment: @vincent I did not. Look at the edit history. You didn’t post it in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I remembered input it, maybe there is some other problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal Windows Platform offers [`AdaptiveTriggers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.AdaptiveTrigger) just for this purpose.

Under the root content element of your page (usually a `Grid`) you define `VisualState`, that is controlled by an `AdaptiveTrigger` and is displayed when the window width is greater than 1024 effective pixels. The `Setters` then control the changes that should be performed when transitioning between the states.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024"/>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>

            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="gridX.(Grid.Column)" Value="1"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Because `Grid.Column` is an attached property, you need to wrap it in parentheses in the `Setter`'s `Target`. The sample code supposes that your grid has a `x:Name="gridX"` attribute.

Comment: Yes, Dai edited my question and delete <Grid x:Name="gridX"/>.